# gallery instead of camera activity (Tensorflow) in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow

Is it possible to not use the camera activity and load the images from gallery for object detection using Tensorflow object detection API?

Comment: Please only use IDE tags for questions about the tool itself, not for general code questions. Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Also, please see: [Why is "is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously yes!

When you use the camera (not talking about real-time image detection, such as using Yolo with Tensorflow), you take a snapshot image and then you process that bitmap with Tensorflow. Instead of that, what you can do is, select an image from the gallery, convert it to bitmap and then process it using Tensorflow.

If you further need example or sample, I would be happy to help you out. But for that make sure you post or show what you've done or tried so far.

Comment: I have completed real time object detection using tensorflow. now i want to select the image from gallery and detect object  draw with rectangle